# How to program I2C slave mode

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, 8051

I am failing to understand how I would code my MCU to listen for it's address on the I2C bus and execute accordingly. A lot of example code in C is for a master device. I would like to better understand how to write code for a slave device. Do I use the SMB0STA status register? I posted a function below that I think would "listen" for the cue to start and output data. `0xA8` is the status code for "Own address + R received. ACK transmitted." according to my C8051F020 MCU datasheet.

```
unsigned char i2c_Slave_Read (void)
{
    unsigned char data_out[8];

    data_out[8] = "LED 1 ON";

    while (SI)
    if (SMB0STA == 0xA8)
    {
        P5 = 0x10;
        SMB0DAT = data_out;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Slave operation is described starting in section 18.3.3 of the [datasheet](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/C8051F02x.pdf)

You program the `SMB0ADR` register with your slave address.  Address detection is done by the hardware, which then gives you an interrupts when data arrives.  You then can read the status in `SMB0STA` to see what is happening, and read/write data using `SMB0DAT`.  See table 18.1, which explains the `SMB0STA` state machines and the actions your code should take.